# How to debug Cython code in Pandas?

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, cython

I have downloaded Pandas source and now trying to debug it.
I modified Makefile:

```
sparse: pandas/src/sparse.pyx
python-dbg setup.py build_ext --inplace --pyrex-gdb

build: clean_pyc
python-dbg setup.py build_ext --inplace --pyrex-gdb

develop: build
-python-dbg setup.py develop --pyrex-gdb
```

Also I have a very simple script:

```
from numpy import asarray
from pandas import algos

v = [4171.0, 0.0]
expAverage = algos.ewma(asarray(v), 50, 1)

print expAverage
```

When I try to run it with python-dbg test1.py, this is what I get:

```
/tmp/1/pandas/pandas/hashtable.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas import algos
  File "/tmp/1/pandas/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: /tmp/1/pandas/pandas/hashtable.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64
[94423 refs]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I actually find it just as easy when debugging cythong to just put in print statements (old school), but is pretty quick.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, I actually found your comment very interesting. I'm neither a Pandas nor Cython/Python user, but I have programmed in SAS. My professors have never taught us to use debuggers, we were always told to just use print statements everywhere to check our programs when compiling. So, in general do you think putting print statements are just as effective as debuggers even if we're using them in other programming languages? Seems like Pandas has more of a consistent syntax than R. Cheers.

Comment: in general debuggers are good (Eg pdb). I was just pointing out that for a relatively simple function and a quick compile-run cycle print statements often suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Obviously, at least one of your (C) extensions that is being loaded has not been compiled with debug info in a way that `python-dbg` can use.

This explanation has the details:

http://hustoknow.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/why-your-python-program-cant-start-when.html

To me it seems like `--with-pydebug` flag is not equivalent / triggers the same actions as `--pyrex-gdb`. BTW, it seems that `--pyrex-gdb` has been renamed to `--cython-gdb`.

2. Can you use `cygdb` or `cython --gdb` instead? It seems like the flag that you're using has been reported not to work: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/K6sjhzUX5JA

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't check it as that was a long time ago  (actually Python code was just a prototype and I rewrote everything in Java).